# How to create an Authentication plugin (interceptop) for ActiveMQ (for MQTT) that uses a JWT (JWS) to authenticate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, mqtt

**I basically need a controlled MQTT broker.**
I need to create authentication and authorization system for MQTT broker made with Embedded ActiveMQ. It will check forI want to use Java (Spring Boot).
I want to disable automatic topic creation. I will manually create then from Java code.
**I want to authorize a user to connect to a topic, whether it is to publish or subscribe. Everything in run-time.**

I have read about plugins from [activemq site](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html). But don't get the full extent, how to create a plugin to authorize for individual topics. I need to be able to modify my whitelist in run time.

Comment: Your title mentions JWT (JWS) but the question doesn't mention anything about it. What is the role of JWT (JWS) here? Also, why do you need to create a custom plugin for authorization rather than just using the built-in authorization functionality to grant `read` and `write` permissions on the necessary topics?

Comment: The topics have to be created in a controlled manner by the server application. No preloaded topic. And I need to assign some topics to some users. All programatically.
I was thinking about giving a user a JWS instead of using MQTT standard Username/Password field and use DB. As I do not want to access DB for each Publush/Subscribe. I was thinking about putting that JWS in Username field and use a custom plugin. 
The request to create topic and sharing of JWS is done using another channel based on simple HTTPS request.

Comment: I can also do with any other broker (preferablly embeddable). But it needs to be free. HiveMQ has similar type of authorization, what I am thinking about ( https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-security-fundamentals-authorization/ ). But it is not free for production.

Comment: Are you asking about the ActiveMQ 5.x broker or the newer [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/) broker?

Comment: I am asking for ActiveMQ broker. But I have no problem switching to ActiveMQ Artemis or any other free to use broker.